# Following Manual Instructions for Bootstrap 3 forms getting yml config error

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, twig, symfony

I'm following directions directly from the manual. I've got this configuration setting in my config.yml

```
twig:
    form:
        resources: ['bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig']
```

haven't got this far but in my base.html.twig i have...

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
          href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
          integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" 
          crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
          href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" 
          integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" 
          crossorigin="anonymous">
    {% block stylesheets %}{% endblock %}
```

And of course the appropriate call for jquery and boostrap.js at bottom of base.html.twig

In any of my templates I have....

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% form_theme form 'bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig' %}


{% block body %} //etc. etc.
```

I get the error:

```
InvalidConfigurationException in ArrayNode.php line 317:
Unrecognized option "form" under "twig"
```

did they change the yml configuration settings and not update it in the manual?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In newer Symfony versions, you must use `form_themes` instead of `form.resources`:

```
# app/config/config.yml
twig:
    form_themes: ['bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig']
```

And, you don't need to add this to your templates:

```
{% form_theme form 'bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig' %}
```

You can safely remove that tag and forms will still use the Bootstrap form theme (because you configured it globally in `config.yml` file).

This is the official documentation about this: http://symfony.com/doc/2.6/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#making-application-wide-customizations

Comment: Thanks for the extra info about not needing to include the form theming in the blocks themselves. That's a nice edition to 3.0

Answer (score 3):

Probably the doc is mysaligned for the related framework version.

Try this:

<kbd>config.yml</kbd>

```
twig:
    form_themes:
        # Bootstrap:
        - bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig
```

take a look at the [TWIG bundle documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/twig.html) here to see a full doc of the related bundle configuration.

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks for quick response, and teaching me a bit more about yml syntax, as both you and @Javier above answers are correct.